# When to use I Or Myself as the object of the sentence

Tags: reflexives

Which is correct?

> "I made lunch for my wife and I"
>   *-or-*
>   "I made lunch for my wife and myself"

--I hear both of them used.

Comment: for my wife and me. preposition + indirect object.

Comment: Do *not* say 'myself' when what you really mean is 'me'. It is a habit that has grown, ironically, particularly among more educated people. Other people can never talk to *myself*, only to *me*. See [this article](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/reflexive-pronouns) on reflexive pronouns if you're struggling to differentiate between them.

Comment: You use the reflexive pronoun (*myself, himself*, etc.) when the actor is also the target.  Here, the actor (the person performing the action of making lunch) is also the target (the person for whom lunch is being made), so the reflexive pronoun is correct.  (see, for example, [English Club's](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-reflexive.htm) page on reflexive pronouns.)

Comment: @Hellion Agreed. You don't say "I made lunch for me," or "he made lunch for him." You say "I made lunch for myself," and "he made lunch for himself."

Comment: I made lunch for myself and my wife. I made lunch for my wife and me. I made lunch for me and my wife. NOT: for I.

Comment: The non-reflexive "me" (not "I") is fine since the subject "I" is its only possible antecedent. The reflexive form "myself" would thus be optional here.

Comment: I'm surprised that "me / myself / I" isn't a common duplicate with a pre-existing question that could be linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Basing my answer on ESL-teacher and native-speaker intuition here, but I think both are wrong.

The reflexive pronoun is seldom (read: never) used if there are more subject pronouns than just the subject.

So in this example, I don't see why you wouldn't just use:

"I made lunch for my wife and me."

You should use "me" here because it's "for whom".

Comment: Nice answer! Concisely said.

Comment: I'd go along with that, but add that the reflexive "myself" is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. "I made lunch for my wife and I."

Incorrect because you're putting a subject pronoun in the object position.  (This is a common mistake made by many native speakers of English.)

> 2. "I made lunch for my wife and myself."

Correct.  It will be easier to see why it needs to be reflexive if we omit the other person:  *"I made lunch for myself."*

Here is an example of a sentence with the plain, non-reflexive pronoun "me":

> 3. "My wife made lunch for my mother and me."

Comment: You have committed a rookie mistake. You have tried to regularise the grammar according to what you think would be logical. Coordinations of pronouns don't follow the same rules in terms of agreement as single ones.

Comment: @Araucaria - Calling me a rookie doesn't convince me.  Would you mind posting an Answer?  I am interested to understand your point of view.

Comment: I wasn't calling you a rookie, was just saying that that's a rookie mistake :) See the venerable [F.E.'s answer here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/is-it-i-or-me-in-keep-tom-and-i-me-updated/59914#59914). It includes info from vetted grammar sources such as the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*.

Comment: @Araucaria - If you want to quote F.E.'s answer in a post here, it would be helpful to signal which part of that treatise would be relevant to whether to use the reflexive pronoun or not.  Similarly, if you want to quote from the *Cambridge Grammar*, it would be helpful to signal which part is relevant to this particular question.

Comment: The part of your answer which is problematic is the bit where you say *"Incorrect because you're putting a subject pronoun in the object position. (This is a common mistake made by many native speakers of English.)"*. <--as shown in F.E.'s quote from *CamGEL*, this description is not accurate. I am not saying F.E.'s post is an answer to this OP's question.

Comment: @Araucaria - The F.E. post is so lengthy that some guidance to finding the portion you're citing would be helpful.  Also, if you disagree with either the conclusion or the reasoning in the answers given here, it would be extremely helpful if you were to write your own answer where you lay things out in an easy to understand way that even people who make rookie mistakes can follow easily.

Comment: The short answer at the top of the post is not very long and includes a quote from H&P :)

Comment: @Araucaria - not sure what you're referring to.  "Short answer at the top of the post" -- is that in the question, the other answer provided so far, a comment, or what?  Remember, I wrote a rookie answer; I don't understand "H&P," and I'm not finding what you're referring to.

Comment: That part at the beginning of F.E.'s post entitled *QUICK ANSWER IN A NUTSHELL:*

Comment: @Araucaria - F.E. wrote, "it is nevertheless condemned as incorrect or illiterate by many usage manuals."  OP acknowledges having heard both versions in spoken English, but wants to know what is correct.

Comment: Yes, but you've missed out the "pedants" part of that and ignored the fact that H&P plainly say that such behaviour is indefensible given the bald facts of the language.